# How can I cancel a pending asynchronous request and unregister invocation callback using Jersey Client 2.2.x?

Tags: java, rest, asynchronous, jersey, jersey-client

I have a simple REST service with a sleep method which doesn't do anything more than sleep for the specified time in milliseconds and then returns with a No Content response. My RESTTest class tries to invoke `http://localhost:8080/myapp/rest/sleep/7500` first (to sleep for 7.5 seconds) but only waits for 5 seconds. After the 5 seconds it cancels the received Future (trying to cancel the pending request) and invokes `http://localhost:8080/myapp/rest/sleep/5000` (to sleep for 5 seconds) and waits for 5 seconds.

```
public class RESTTest {
    private final Client client = ClientBuilder.newClient();
    private final ReentrantLock lock = new ReentrantLock();
    private final Condition responseReceived = lock.newCondition();

    public static void main(final String... arguments) {
        new RESTTest().listen(10000);
    }

    public void listen(final long time) {
        System.out.println("Listen for " + time + " ms.");
        Future<Response> _response =
            client.
                target("http://localhost:8080/myapp/rest/sleep/" + time)).
                request().
                async().
                    get(
                        new InvocationCallback<Response>() {
                            public void completed(final Response response) {
                                System.out.println("COMPLETED");
                                lock.lock();
                                try {
                                    responseReceived.signalAll();
                                } finally {
                                    lock.unlock();
                                }
                            }

                            public void failed(final Throwable throwable) {
                                lock.lock();
                                try {
                                    responseReceived.signalAll();
                                } finally {
                                    lock.unlock();
                                }
                            }
                        });
        lock.lock();
        try {
            System.out.println("Waiting for 5000 ms.");
            if (!responseReceived.await(5000, TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS)) {
                System.out.println("Timed out!");
                _response.cancel(true);
                listen(5000);
            } else {
                System.out.println("Response received.");
            }
        } catch (final InterruptedException exception) {
            // Do nothing.
        } finally {
            lock.unlock();
        }
    }
}
```

Now I'd expect to see the "COMPLETED" string printed only once, and the "Response received." string printed only once as well. However, the "COMPLETED" string gets printed twice!

```
Listen for 7500 ms.
Waiting for 5000 ms.
Timed out!
Listen for 5000 ms.
Waiting for 5000 ms.
COMPLETED
Response received.
COMPLETED
```

What am I missing here?

Thanks,

Answer (score 0):

I am sure you figured it out but here is an extremely modular solution that you can use with simple Guava ListenableFuture. You don't have to pool the responses like I am doing in the Futures.allAsList of course but you can do something like this at the end and remove your CountDownLatch.

BTW I am pretty sure your problem is a threading issue. You are seeing the COMPLETED because the callback is being invoked after your next call to listen(5000). Keep in mind that async will be threaded so output to the console can get delayed until the next context switch. The server is probably responding just after your 7500 semaphore unlocks.

```
private Client client;

@Before
public void setup() {
    final ClientConfig clientConfig = new ClientConfig();
    clientConfig.register(OrtbBidRequestBodyReader.class);
    clientConfig.register(OrtbBidRequestBodyWriter.class);
    clientConfig.connectorProvider(new CachingConnectorProvider(new HttpUrlConnectorProvider()));
    clientConfig.property(ClientProperties.ASYNC_THREADPOOL_SIZE, 3);
    client = ClientBuilder.newClient(clientConfig);
}

@Test
public void testAsync() throws InterruptedException, ExecutionException, JsonProcessingException {

    final WebTarget target = client
            .target("http://localhost:8081/dsp-receiver-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT/ortb/bid/123123?testbid=bid");

    final AtomicInteger successcount = new AtomicInteger();
    final AtomicInteger noBid = new AtomicInteger();
    final AtomicInteger clientError = new AtomicInteger();

    final InvocationCallback<Response> callback = new InvocationCallback<Response>() {
        @Override
        public void completed(final Response response) {
            if (response.getStatus() == 200) {
                successcount.incrementAndGet();
            } else if (response.getStatus() == 204) {
                noBid.incrementAndGet();
            } else {
                clientError.incrementAndGet();
            }
        }

        @Override
        public void failed(final Throwable e) {
            clientError.incrementAndGet();
            logger.info("Client Error", e);
        }
    };

    final Entity<OrtbBidRequest> entity = Entity.entity(testBidRequest, MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON);
    final List<ListenableFuture<Response>> allFutures = Lists.newArrayList();
    final Stopwatch stopwatch = Stopwatch.createStarted();
    for (int i = 0; i < 100000; i++) {
        logger.info("Running request {}", i);
        final Future<Response> future = target.request().accept(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON).async().post(entity,
                callback);
        final ListenableFuture<Response> response = JdkFutureAdapters.listenInPoolThread(future);
        allFutures.add(response);

        // For each 100 of requests we will wait on them, otherwise we
        // may run out of memory. This is really just to test the stamina
        // of the dsp
        if (i % 200 == 0) {
            Futures.allAsList(allFutures).get();
            allFutures.clear();
        }
    }

    logger.info("success count {}  nobid {} client error {} ", successcount, noBid, clientError);
    logger.info("Total time {} ms ", stopwatch.stop());
}
```